# How to prove that $\lim\limits_{x,y\to 0} \frac{1}{x^2+y^2}$ does exist and what's its result?

Tags: limits, infinity

How to prove that the following limit doesn't  exist ?

$$\lim\limits_{x,y\to 0} \frac{1}{x^2+y^2}$$

Comment: this limit does exist

Comment: Hint: $2xy\leq x^2 + y^2$.

Comment: The limit to $0$ obviously isn't finite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We will show that 
$$\lim\limits_{x,y\to 0} \frac{1}{x^2+y^2} = \infty$$

Remember that $\lim_{x \to a} f(x) = \infty \iff \forall_{\epsilon > 0} \exists_{\delta > 0}: |x - a| < \delta \Rightarrow f(x) > \frac1\epsilon$

That is, the limit of $f(x)$ goes to infinity when $x$ goes to $a$ iff, after you set a very big target number $T$, you can make $f(x)$ bigger than that target $T$ by making $x$ close to $a$. In the formal definition we instead choose a very small $\epsilon$, making $\frac1\epsilon$ very big.

Let us set some $\epsilon$. We need to show that we can make

$$\frac{1}{x^2+y^2} > \frac1\epsilon$$

by making $x, y$ very close to 0.

By commodity, we can assume that $x = y$ and then we get

$$\frac{1}{x^2+x^2} = \frac{1}{2x^2} > \frac1\epsilon$$

We can easily manipulate the expression getting

$$\frac{1}{2x^2} > \frac1\epsilon \iff\\
\frac{1}{x^2} > \frac2\epsilon \iff\\
x^2 < \frac\epsilon2 \iff\\
x < \sqrt{\frac\epsilon2}$$

That is, if $x, y < \sqrt{\frac\epsilon2}$, then $\frac{1}{x^2+y^2}$ will be greater than $\frac1\epsilon$ and thus we can make it infinitely big by making $x, y$ infinitely small and we established that

$$\lim\limits_{x,y\to 0} \frac{1}{x^2+y^2} = \infty$$

Comment: Hm why a downvote? If you could pinpoint where I am wrong/answered badly, I would appreciate. That way I can improve more.

Comment: In what way does the identity $x^2+y^2=\|(x,y)\|^2$ help ? It is just a rewrite.

Comment: @YvesDaoust ||(x, y)|| can be, in my opinion, more simply viewed as a value that tends to infinity. I assumed the OP was familiar with the limit of $\frac1x$ when $x \to \infty$ and even though the norm depends on the two variables, it is itself a single number.

Comment: @RSerrao i am aware of the 1/x limit when x tends to infinity,i wanted a better explanation of the required limit.

Comment: I am so so so sorry i meant the limit for (x,y)->(0,0)

Comment: @RSerrao I am so sorry, been under a lot of stress and i wrote that ... of course i am aware of the limit of (x,y)-> infinity, the problems was when (x,y)->(0,0). I have to check if the limits exists for a continuity matter

Comment: @RSerrao: I can't adhere to such an argument. $x^2+y^2$ is also a scalar, no progress is made.

Comment: @CatalinGhita check my answer now please.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I certainly get your point; I am just of the opinion that certain things are more easily understood if written in other ways, even knowing that I just wrote a trivial equivalence. Nonetheless, the question was misspelled and you may be more fond of my new answer. I am open to new critiques if you find my answer worthy of it. If you find my answer fine enough, please consider removing your downvote.

Comment: @RSerrao Yes it is definitely better. Therefore 1/(0+0)->infinity is aswell correct?

Comment: @CatalinGhita Yes, one *could* say that. But the **limit** is $\infty$.

Answer (score 0):

First step is to determine if the function is continuous near the limit.

We know that $\frac{1}{x^2+y^2}$ is only discontinuous at $(0,0)$. Since we are evaluating the function no where near that the path to taking the limit doesn't matter.

I'll choose (as @RSerraro did) the path of $||x^2+y^2||\rightarrow \infty$.Thus:
\begin{equation}
\lim_{x,y\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{x^2+y^2}=\lim_{||x+y||^2\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{x^2+y^2} = \lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{x^2}=0
\end{equation}

For the limit as $(x,y)\rightarrow 0$:

I will note that I can reparamterize this function as:$\frac{1}{r^2}$

I notice that the function is independent of angle of approach so the limit can be rewritten as purely a function of $r$:

\begin{equation}
\lim_{r\rightarrow 0,\theta \rightarrow ??} \frac{1}{r^2} = \lim_{r\rightarrow 0} \frac{1}{r^2} = \infty
\end{equation}

Comment: i misspelled (x,y)->(inf), i meant (x,y)->(0,0). I am so sorry